# Content creation screen: Add another field conditionally

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following in D7:
I have a list field in a custom content type. The list contains 8 items. When creating content of this content type, the user can only select one item from this list. **But** there are two items from this list that I would like to have their own sub-lists. How would I have Drupal conditionally show another list if one of these items were selected? (This is all happening on the content creation screen).

**Update**
This is not a duplicate of the question you have referenced because this is regarding Drupal 7 content creation. The "Conditional Fields" module was built for Drupal 6 and is not fit for production, as per the module page, in Drupal 7 pages. I am looking for a stable, maintainable solution for a production website.

Comment: The other question definitely looks like a dup to me. Whether the existing answers are applicable to you doesn't actually matter, the question has already been asked and no-one is helped by asking it again.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [Hierarchical Select module](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). It provides this kind of functionality for vocabularies.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question you have referenced because this is regarding Drupal 7 content creation. The "Conditional Fields" module was built for Drupal 6 and is not fit for production, as per the module page, in Drupal 7 pages. I am looking for a stable, maintainable solution for a production website.